# validation input zipcode Mexico zippopotam

Tags: javascript, html

I need to validate the zip code if is true of Mexico.

I have a form and you can see the code next, I don't understand why don't consider the validation, what is wrong?

I pasted the code of an example I found

http://parsleyjs.org/doc/examples/ajax.html

```js
// on js
Parsley.addValidator('zip', {
            validateString: function (value) {
                // Zippopotam.us returns a status 404 for incorrect zip codes,
                // so we simply return the ajax request:
                return $.ajax({
                    url: '//www.zippopotam.us/mx/' + value,
                    success: function (result, success) {
                        $('#zipState').val(result['places'][0]['state abbreviation']);
                    },
                    error: function (result, success) {
                        $('#zipState').val('');
                    }
                })
            }
        });
```

```html
//input in form
  <div class="consumidor_cp_right">
  <div class="consumidor_cp">
 <label for="zip"><span>*</span>C.P.</label>
 <input type="text" class="input_control" name="zip" id="cp" data-parsley-length="[5,5]" required="" data-parsley-zip="mx">
</div>
</div>
```

But the validation has not happened. I it think is the way I called the validation on the input but I'm not sure what exactly I should call it or make reference to it.

Answer (score 0):

It worked on my end,

See the full code below,

```
<h1>Custom validators</h1>
<h3>Simple ajax request</h3>
<form data-parsley-validate="">
  <input type="text" class="input_control" name="zip" id="cp" data-parsley-length="[5,5]" required="" data-parsley-zip="mx">
  <br>
  <input type="submit" value="validate">

</form>
<script
  src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="parsley.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
Parsley.addValidator('zip', {
  validateString: function(value) {
    // Zippopotam.us returns a status 404 for incorrect zip codes,
    // so we simply return the ajax request:
    return $.ajax({
        url: '//www.zippopotam.us/mx/' + value,
        success: function (result, success) {
            alert(result['places'][0]['state abbreviation']);
        },
        error: function (result, success) {
            alert('Not found');
        }
    })
  },
  messages: {en: 'There is no such zip for the country "%s"'}
});
Parsley.on('form:submit', function() {
  return false; // Don't submit form for this demo
});
</script>
```

- Test it with zip code 20304, it returns **AGU**
- Test it with zip code 90098, it returns nothing and alerts **Not
  found**

Check if your parsley js is included and make sure you are not using slim version of jQuery as it doesn't support ajax.